# How can I remove this Error in Django models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I created a amount field in models.py,
I run **python manage.py makemigrations** and **python manage.py migrate**
It gave me error **ValueError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got ''.**
then I removed this amount field line from my code and again did makemigrations and migrate command. now again it it showing same error. when I open Django admin page and select my model name which is Orderss . It gives me error that there is no filed name amount

```
class Orders(models.Model):
order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
items_json = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
# amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=12, default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your migrations and delete you db.sqlite3
and then

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations 
python3 manage.py migrate
```

hope it work

Answer (score 0):

When you did the migration first time, you’ve created the table in the database with ‘amount’ column. The second migration did’t remove this column. You can go to your database shell and remove the column there. It depends on the type of database you use, but you you might try to do it this way:

```
python manage.py dbshell 

mysql> | psql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP column <COLUMN_NAME>;
```

Then exit the shell and sync

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**.In the Migration folder **delete** all files except **`__init__.py`** and then **run**

> **`python manage.py makemigrations`**   and

> **`python manage.py migrate`**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).